# Which statistical test to use

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a table containing, for each patient, the count of synonymous and non-synonymous mutations in primary vs metastasis (total 20 patients) like the following.

```
1P  1M  2P  2M  3P  3M  4P  4M ... 20P  20M
20  25  31  23  27  35  39  32 ... 41   38
60  50  61  63  55  71  49  64 ... 71   76
```

where the first row shows counts of synonymous mutations and the second one shows the count of non-synonymous mutations. As an example, patient 1 has 20 syn mutations vs 60 non-syn mutation in primary while the same patient has 25 syn mutations vs 50 non-syn mutations in metastasis.

I want to test the following hypothesis. "The ratio of synonymous to non-synonymous mutations does not change significantly between primary and metastasis"

I was wondering which test would be appropriate for testing this hypothesis. Some example in R will be very helpful for understanding purpose.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I realised that the description of the data may not be easy for some to grasp, so I am dividing the above table into two seperate tables, one for primary and another for metastasis as follows.

syn-count = count of synonymous mutations; non-syn-count = count of non-synonymous mutations; header gives patient number 1-20

```
                 p1  p2  p3  p4 ... p20
"syn-count"      20  31  27  39 ... 41 
"non-syn count"  60  61  55  49 ... 71 
     TABLE: synonymous and non synonymous mutations in primary 
                   tumor of 20 patients
```

```
                p1  p2  p3  p4 ... p20
"syn-count"     25  23  35  32 ... 41 
"non-syn count" 50  63  71  64 ... 71 
     TABLE: synonymous and non synonymous mutations in metastatic 
                   tumor of 20 patients
```

Comment: Sorry--what does the first row signify again? Is the numeric portion the patient identifier and the letter the identifier of primary and metastasis?  You should transform your data to long format to make it easier to analyze

Comment: @marquisdecarabas The header (e.g. 1P) shows which patient (1) and which tumor type (P-primary; M-metastasis). Given "n" genes mutated in a patient, the first row shows p (out of n) genes which have synonymous mutation, the second rows shows (n-p) genes which have non-synonymous mutation.

Comment: The meanings are evident. I believe the spirit of the comment by @marquis was to suggest that a more appropriate structuring of your data could help you understand them better, model them better, and analyze them better (as well as help readers provide sample calculations if they choose). Currently you have important information buried within a cryptic code contained in a single field: namely, patient identifier and metastasis. You would be (much) better off with a $20\times 4$ array in which the columns give a patient id, "metastasis" indicator, "synonymous" indicator, and count.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you could take. You could form the proportion for each person for each tumour type and use one of the many packages in R which fit random effects models (so you would have a fixed effect for metastasis versus primary and a random effect for patient). An alternative would be to consider each patient as giving rise to a 2 by 2 table and compute an appropriate summary statistic from it and then do a meta-analysis of the resulting statistics. I would use `metafor` for this but there are many other packages.

Comment: The proposal of a random-effects model sounds like a good approach (especially using a GLM as appropriate for counts).  However, (1) creating proportions destroys important information about the overall magnitudes of the counts and (2) why perform a meta-analysis when you have the raw data?  There appears to be no conceivable advantage to that.

Comment: I think the OP would be using the raw data @whuber and I do not see too much difference between analysing the log odds in a mixed effects logistic regression framework and summarising the log odds in a meta-analysis framework. It might be better to analyse risk difference of course but I think that is a scientific/clinical question for the OP.